# Мультипроцессинг в питоне: почему Done интервал времени больше интервалов в дочерних процессах

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.x, multiprocessing

Всем привет! 
Решил на выходных разобраться в мультипроцессорности в питоне. Т.к. многопоточность залочена GIL, в интернете очень много информации о модуле multiprocessing для распараллеливания задач

Набросал тестовую программку (os Windows):

```
import timeit    
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

a = timeit.default_timer()
def writer(name):
    print ('start child process with id: ', os.getpid())
    with open(name + "txt", 'w') as fout:
        for i in xrange(500000):
            print >> fout, name
    print(timeit.default_timer() - a)

if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Process(target=writer, args=('mom',))
    p1 = Process(target=writer, args=('olk',))
    p.start()
    p1.start()
    print('Done ' + str(timeit.default_timer() - a))
```

По моей задумке процессы начинают выполняться параллельно в фоне, и сначала должна появиться надпись с Done. В принципе так оно и происходит, но с непредсказуемым временем:

```
(u'start child process with id: ', 3492)
Done 1.73671324643
0.852093865662
(u'start child process with id: ', 4560)
0.933829923571
```

Откуда берется 1.73671324643 сек, ведь Done выполняется раньше всех?

Comment: какая OS? Точка отсчёта для `timer.default_timer` какая (запуск процесса?) 2- Чему `a` равно в разных процессах?

Comment: ОС Windows 7 32-bit. Точка отсчета a = timeit.default_timer() в основном процессе. Ставил ее внутрь if, результат тот же. По идее a получает время сразу при запуске, непосредственно перед запуском процессов. Вроде в отдельный процесс как-то особенно переменные из основного передавать не нужно?

Comment: `a` это не точка отсчёта для timeit.default_timer.  К примеру, точка отсчёта для time.time это time.gmtime(0) (1970-01-01). Точка отсчёта для  time.clock на Windows — это время (wall-clock) прошедшее с первого вызова. Какую функцию timeit.default_timer вызывает на вашей версии Питона? 2- следует понимать, что `a` в одном процессе и `a` в другом процессе это разные объекты (вероятно что значения совпадают, но следует явно проверить). Попробуйте ответить на оба оставшихся вопроса из моего первого комментария.